# Adding "default" to multiple columns in one single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the query:

```
ALTER TABLE table1ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR col1
```

I have 100 existing columns to add default(''), is there anything like

```
ALTER TABLE table1ADD  DEFAULT ('') FOR col1, col2, col3...
```

which I can use?

Comment: I'm using microsoft sql server

Comment: Could try a technique similar to the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3644728/1521230

Comment: That sounds like a horrible thing to do - is this just some irrational dislike of `NULL`? Why is an empty string preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use SQL to generate the SQL statements.

```sql
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE table1 ADD DEFAULT ('''') FOR '+ COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='table1'
```

This will generate an ALTER TABLE line for each and every column in your table. Don't worry, these lines are just text output! Now you can copy to clipboard, paste into a SQL Server Management Studio window, delete the lines that you DON'T want the default applied to, and execute.

Comment: turns out you *could* have done it in one execution, by using the SELECT I provided as the source to a cursor ... but there's no real gain for a one-time change like this.