# Why can't you Alter multiple columns within the same line

Tags: t-sql, alter-table, alter

I was simply wondering if there was a performance or other technical reason for you to be unable to perform a **ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN** statement with multiple columns within the same line e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE tblGeneric ALTER COLUMN Generic1 VARCHAR(255), Generic2 VARCHAR(255);
```

*This is exclusively a restriction of t-sql as you can in fact comma separate columns with the **MODIFY** statement of mysql.*

I just thought it odd, especially considering the **MODIFY** of mysql, that you can do a same line multi **ALTER TABLE ADD** statement but not a same line multi **ALTER**. I was just wondered if there is any particular documented reason for this or at least if it's in a issues list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ALTER multiple columns at once in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465560/how-to-alter-multiple-columns-at-once-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` `T-SQL` doesn't allow multiple columns to be changed in one `ALTER TABLE` command (unlike some other languages where it's possible).

Please follow this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190273.aspx) for `ALTER` command syntax and explanation.

However, you can do multiple `ADD` or multiple `DROP` `COLUMN`, but just one `ALTER COLUMN`.