# Change multiple columns with one single migration change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following migration. Is there a way to run these changes in one change than 3?

```
def change
 change_column :comments, :attr_1, :string, null: true
 change_column :comments, :attr_2, :string, null: true
 change_column :comments, :attr_3, :string, null: true
end
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you concerned about running three migrations? This kind of thing is perfectly normal for a Rails app.

Comment: I know this comment is super old, but in case anyone comes back here. For me, I had a really large table and I needed to change multiple columns, which would force a reindex and table lock for each statement. Though I was okay with some downtime during the change, 3x the downtime isn't practical. Unfortunately, there isn't a solution to this with ALTER TABLE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465560/how-to-alter-multiple-columns-at-once-in-sql-server/17480817

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is no. The `change_column` method is configured to take arguments for table name, column name, and an options hash. The source code for `change_column` can be found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0fe76197d2622674e1796a9a000995a7a1f6622b/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb

The only line in the `change_column` method is:
`execute("ALTER TABLE #{quote_table_name(table_name)} #{change_column_sql(table_name, column_name, type, options)}")`

which executes an `ALTER` script on the table name passed as the first argument. You can't pass an array of tables/columns as arguments, so you have to do them one at a time. This paradigm is fairly typical in Rails migrations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the change_table function with bulk set to true which will run the alter as a single MySQL query and be much faster than running individually. Example is below.

```
def change
 change_table(:comments, bulk: true) do |t|
  t.change :attr_1, :string, null: true
  t.change :attr_2, :string, null: true
  t.change :attr_3, :string, null: true
 end
end
```