# Script to change Null values for all columns in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a SQL Server script or query which turns `Null` values to user defined default values for all columns in a table.

I know we can do column by column but my table contains 300 columns.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Alter Mulitple Columns datatype in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465560/how-to-alter-mulitple-columns-datatype-in-sql-server)

Comment: I would be looking into why your table has 300 columns. That is almost always a sign of a very poor architecture which is generally the result of improper normalization. I think you need to take a long hard look at your table structure before you spend the effort of adding default values.

Comment: He may be stuck with one of those 'enterprise' systems that generate huge tables. The issue here is that he is trying to get us write a huge script for him, which I am afraid is out of scope for a Q&A site like this. At least I would not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written my query to set the values to 0.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE [Your Table] SET ' 
        + c.name + ' = COALESCE(' 
        + c.name + ',''0'')'  FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = '[Your table]'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The script you gave will make default value for column to NULL. But I want all null values in column to '0'

Comment: @neoo I have rewritten the query. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hey thanks for the script that's exactly what I am looking for. I am able to generate my required query.