# Sum data stored in a datatable column in string format

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a datatable in my vb .net solution. let's say the datatable (let's call it MyTable) has 2 columns: `Emp_id` and `Emp_cost`.
I want to calculate the sum of `Emp_cost` for a specific `Emp_id`. For example, in the example below I want to get 1500 as `Emp_cost` for `Emp_id = "1210"`. I wanted to use LINQ however, data stored in the `Emp_cost` column are in string format. Is there anyway to use LINQ (instead of using For) for calculation the total cost? (or something like: `MyTable.Compute("Sum(Emp_cost)", "Emp_id = 1210")`?

| Emp_id | Emp_cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1210 | 500 |
| 1210 | 1000 |
| 1220 | 100 |

Comment: Convert your database Emp_id to INT and Emp_cost to DECIMAL. That is going to fix this problem, and many many more you are about to have.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, would you please let me know how to convert data already exist in a datatable to another format?

Comment: Consult [How to ALTER multiple columns at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465560/)